# Trying to store NSString into UITableViewCell with the given variables

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using the card io API which scans credit cards and then takes that information to be used in a table view. I have the following fields that I have to fill:

-credit card number
-cvv
-Expiration Date (I appended the strings since they are used as separate variables)

here's my code:

.m file

```
- (void)userDidProvideCreditCardInfo:(CardIOCreditCardInfo *)info inPaymentViewController:(CardIOPaymentViewController *)scanViewController {

        BillingTableViewCell *aCell;

        NSString *myString = info.expiryMonth;
        NSString *otherString = [myString stringByAppendingString: info.expiryYear];

        aCell = (BillingTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
        aCell.text.text = info.cardType;


        aCell = (BillingTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]];
        aCell.textLabel.text = info.cardNumber;


        aCell = (BillingTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0]];
        aCell.text.text = info.cvv;


        aCell = (BillingTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:0]];
        aCell.text.text = info.zip;


        aCell = (BillingTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:5 inSection:0]];
        aCell.text.text = otherString;


    [scanViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

and here's my .h file:

```
property(nonatomic, assign, readwrite) NSUInteger expiryMonth;  
@property(nonatomic, assign, readwrite) NSUInteger expiryYear;  
@property(nonatomic, copy, readwrite) NSString *cvv;
@property(nonatomic, copy, readwrite) NSString *zip;
```

I keep coming up with thread errors and the information does not get put into the text fields. What am I doing wrong?

error:

```
0x38fa65c6:  push.w {r3, r4}
0x38fa65ca:  ldr    r4, [r0] thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x5)
0x38fa65cc:  lsr.w  r9, r1, #2
```

Comment: I edited my question and added the error codes.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to populate a UITableView you should implement the the following two methods:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableview:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Then in the first method (`tableView: cellForIndexPath:`) you'd create a `UITableViewCell` and  populate its properties with your data.

Make sure you set your ViewController to be the delegate and datasource for the UITableView.